# How to slice or separate integer numbers and assign them to different variables

Tags: c#, algorithm

For example, if I have a variable:

```
uint version = 001001020;
```

This version has 9 digits, and I want to divide them up to 3 variables.

- the first variable will have 001
- the second variable will have 001 and
- the third variable will have 020

I tried using slice like this:

```
first_variable = version.Slice(0,6)
second_var = version.Slice(3,3)
third_var = version.Slice(6,0)
```

It seems to only work on strings, not `uint`.

Comment: yes, it works on strings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k2z74cd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx so if you don't care about performance why not convert version to a string and then slice it?

Comment: The "Slice" method is a JScript string object method, not available in C# or .NET. Substring exists though.

Comment: @DlanodKcud -- could work, but didn't apply because like you said, I care about performance in this case.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen -- I haven't tested it yet, but this website shows it's available in C# http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-slice

EDIT: just realized it's an extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with division and remainder:

```
uint first_variable = version / 1000000;
uint second_variable = (version / 1000) % 1000;
uint third_variable = version % 1000;
```

`/ 1000000` will shift the number 6 digits to the right, discarding all the rightmost digits, and `% 1000` will keep only whatever is below 1000.

Comment: You'll need to divide by 1000000 (6 zeroes) to shift 6 digits.

Comment: What do you mean? You asked how to pick apart the number, not to build it back up. What exactly is the question here? A numeric variable in .NET (or most programming languages for that matter) has no concept of leading zeros. `001` is exactly the same as `01` and `1`.

Comment: I didn't want to build it back up, I was thinking other way around. it doesn't matter you're right. I thought I needed the 0's in there. your help is appreciated!